# The import javax.annotation.PostConstruct cannot be resolved

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

When i import the following packages:

```
import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.annotation.PreDestroy;
```

I got the following result:

```
The import javax.annotation.PostConstruct cannot be resolved
```

Comment: Now it is working after adding the dependencies <dependency>
  <groupId>javax.annotation</groupId>
  <artifactId>javax.annotation-api</artifactId>
  <version>1.3.2</version>
</dependency>

Comment: If you are getting this in eclipse, refer this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51630397/import-javax-annotation-cannot-be-resolved-in-eclipses-java-10-compiler/51630783

Comment: clean and build or you need to be aware if you have the dependency in your pom.

Answer (score 35):

If you are using spring-boot and below dependency then it should add `javax.annotation` automatically from parent starter.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

For non spring boot starter data jpa add below dependency in pom.xml

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>javax.annotation</groupId>
  <artifactId>javax.annotation-api</artifactId>
  <version>1.3.2</version>
</dependency>
```

Update 2023:

The package has been renamed to jakarta.annotation.

Comment: Also the package has been renamed to jakarta.annotation.